# Powershell Error Open Edx deployment on Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, edx

Why doest this script return diff  error on Windows10 and Mac for the same Powershell Version?
Script executed:
[image]
[image: Mac error]

[image: Windows errors returned]

Comment: I had a suggestion, you had better provide your script as texts not a picture. It is more easy to analyze your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, Azure PowerShell on Mac is in preview. It does not have full functions of Windows PowerShell. Parameter `ServicePrincipalName` is not supported on Mac now, so you get the error.

According to the error on Windows PowerShell. It seems that your application ID or password wrong. Do you check your them? You could use the following cmdlets to create service principal and logon Azure.

```
#login Azure
Login-AzureRmAccount

#create RM AD application
$app = New-AzureRmADApplication –DisplayName "<Your Application Display Name>" –HomePage "<http://YourApplicationHomePage>" –IdentifierUris "<http://YourApplicationUri>" –Password "<Your Password>"

#create a service principal for that application
New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal –ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId

#Assign that service principal a role. 
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment –RoleDefinitionName Reader –ServicePrincipalName $app.ApplicationId

#Authenticating using a service principal
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "<Your Password>" -AsPlainText –Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName pscredential –ArgumentList "<Your UserName>", $pass
Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $cred -ServicePrincipal –TenantId <Your TenantId>
```

More information please refer to this [link](https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/01/azure-resource-manager-authentication-from-a-powershell-script/).

Comment: Thanks Walter for your help, I Went. through all script line by line and I narrowed it here. IT was obvious. why does the script want to initiallize a Subscription Name that does already exists.  Second point, all azure script Cmdlets moved to Rm.  so what does that. set-azureSuccription do here!. 
I replied to all my tweets and forum questions in order to help all those who are trying to deploy the existent  wrong line of script script. Specialy an office hour for deployment support is scheduled next week.   Thanks

Comment: @SAM.Am Sorry, I did not look at the last cmdlet carefully because `Login-AzureRmaccount` throws an error. When the cmdlet `Login-AzureRmaccount` executes failed, it does not execute cmdlet `select-Azuresubscription`. Now, could you execute `Login-AzureRmaccount` successufly? How do you solve it? If my answer is helpful, you could accept it. It will help more people.

Comment: your comments gave me few clues about the wrong cmdlet. Thanks Walter , it was a nice and professional discussion with you.

Answer (score 1):

I  found it. finally   thanks to the collaboration of Microsoft support:

this line of code.

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $AzureSubscriptionName| Out-Null
```

Is not correct.  It should be:

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName $AzureSubscriptionName| Out-Null
```